# AS2 addCallback Type mismatch

Tags: actionscript-2

So I don't get this at all. When I put

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback('startppt', null,"PlayPPT");
```

I get Type mismatch.  However if i put

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback('startppt',"PlayPPT");
```

It takes it fine.  Doesn't work when I try to call the function.  I used JQuery, normal Javascript just about everything.  I think it has something to do with this issue but not certain.  THIS IS ACTIONSCRIPT 2 and I check the publishing settings.  Any ideas or suggestions would be awesome thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that it should be

```
ExternalInterface.addCallBack('startppt', null, PlayPPT);
```

It wasn't the null as mismatch it was the last part I was sending a string when it was expecting a function.